# Чекбокс "Выбрать все" выбирает все чекбоксы, и наоборот

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

При выборе главного `checkbox`'а выбираются все остальные, привязанные к нему, и наоборот, при выборе всех привязанных выбирается и главный.

Реализовать необходимо так, чтобы можно было использовать несколько групп на странице в пределах одной формы.

Поэтому сейчас реализовано так: у главного `checkbox`'а есть id, который совпадает с классами зависимых `checkbox`'ов. Классы могут быть любые - главное что они совпадают с id главного `checkbox`'а.

Рабочий код можно посмотреть ниже, но он слишком массивный. Есть ли более элегантные решения, желательно легко модифицируемые?

```js
$(document).on("change", "input[type=checkbox]", function() { // По изменению checkbox'а
    if ($(this).attr('class')) {
        var CBgroupID = $(this).attr('class');
    }
    if (($(this).attr('id')) && ($('input[type="checkbox"].' + $(this).attr('id')).length)) { 
        var CBgroupID = $(this).attr('id');
        if (this.checked) {
            $('input[type="checkbox"].' + CBgroupID).attr('checked', 'checked');
            $('input[type="button"][class*="' + CBgroupID + '"]').removeAttr('disabled');
        } else {
            $('input[type="checkbox"].' + CBgroupID).removeAttr('checked');
            $('input[type="button"][class*="' + CBgroupID+'"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    }
    if (!CBgroupID) {
        return;
    }
    if ($('input[type="checkbox"].' + CBgroupID + ':not(:checked)').length) {
        $('input[type="checkbox"]#' + CBgroupID).removeAttr('checked');
    } else {
        $('input[type="checkbox"]#' + CBgroupID).attr('checked', 'checked');
    }
    if ($('input[type="checkbox"].' + CBgroupID+':checked').length) {
        $('input[type="button"][class*="' + CBgroupID + '"]').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        $('input[type="button"][class*="' + CBgroupID + '"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
    if ($('input[type="checkbox"].' + CBgroupID + ':checked').length === 1) {
        $('.jToEdit').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        $('.jToEdit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
    delete CBgroupID;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Группа 1</h2>
<input type="checkbox" id="d1" title="Выбрать все">Общий<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="d1" title="Выбрать все"><br />
<input type="checkbox" class="d1" title="Выбрать все"><br />
<input type="checkbox" class="d1" title="Выбрать все">
<h2>Группа 2</h2>
<input type="checkbox" id="d2" title="Выбрать все">Общий<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="d2" title="Выбрать все"><br />
<input type="checkbox" class="d2" title="Выбрать все"><br />
<input type="checkbox" class="d2" title="Выбрать все">
```

[Пример в fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qqL2z7pp/).

Comment: Можно, конечно, с id и class "переехать" на `data-` атрибуты, но кода от этого не уменьшится. Вот что действительно стоит сделать, так это упростить код, начать кэшировать jQuery-объекты и прочее.

Comment: Код для `input[type="button"]` и `.jToEdit` вообще, насколько я понимаю, к вопросу не относится.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
$(document).on('change', 'input[type=checkbox]', function () {
  var $this = $(this), $chks = $(document.getElementsByName(this.name)), $all = $chks.filter(".chk-all");
  
  if ($this.hasClass('chk-all')) {
    $chks.prop('checked', $this.prop('checked'));
  } else switch ($chks.filter(":checked").length) {
    case +$all.prop('checked'):
      $all.prop('checked', false).prop('indeterminate', false);
      break;
    case $chks.length - !!$this.prop('checked'):
      $all.prop('checked', true).prop('indeterminate', false);
      break;
    default:
      $all.prop('indeterminate', true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <label><input type=checkbox name=g1 class=chk-all>All</label>
  <label><input type=checkbox name=g1>1</label>
  <label><input type=checkbox name=g1>2</label>
  <label><input type=checkbox name=g1>3</label>
  <label><input type=checkbox name=g1>4</label>
  <label><input type=checkbox name=g1>5</label>
<p>
  <label><input type=checkbox name=g2 class=chk-all>All</label>
  <label><input type=checkbox name=g2>1</label>
  <label><input type=checkbox name=g2>2</label>
  <label><input type=checkbox name=g2>3</label>
  <label><input type=checkbox name=g2>4</label>
  <label><input type=checkbox name=g2>5</label>
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно:

- `checkbox`'ам в рамках одной группы присвоить уникальное значение `data`-атрибута (например, `data-id`).
- `checkbox`'ам, выбирающим все, дать один класс (например, `.all`), а остальным - другой (например, `one`).

Тогда код может выглядеть следующим образом:

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $(".all").on("change", function() {
        var groupId = $(this).data('id');
        $('.one[data-id="' + groupId + '"]').prop("checked", this.checked);
    });

    $(".one").on("change", function() {
        var groupId = $(this).data('id');
        var allChecked = $('.one[data-id="' + groupId + '"]:not(:checked)').length == 0;
        $('.all[data-id="' + groupId + '"]').prop("checked", allChecked);
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<h2>Группа 1</h2>
<input type="checkbox" class="all" data-id="d1" title="Выбрать все"/>Общий<br/>
<input type="checkbox" class="one" data-id="d1" title="Выбрать"/><br/>
<input type="checkbox" class="one" data-id="d1" title="Выбрать"><br/>
<input type="checkbox" class="one" data-id="d1" title="Выбрать"/>

<h2>Группа 2</h2>
<input type="checkbox" class="all" data-id="d2" title="Выбрать все"/>Общий<br/>
<input type="checkbox" class="one" data-id="d2" title="Выбрать"/><br/>
<input type="checkbox" class="one"data-id="d2" title="Выбрать"/><br/>
<input type="checkbox" class="one" data-id="d2" title="Выбрать"/>
```

[Полный пример в fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qqL2z7pp/1/).

Answer (score 2):

Разбавлю ка я счастливый мирный уголок любителей jQuery суровым и прямолинейным vanilla JavaScript. Реализовывать будем так:

1. засовываем группу `checkbox`'ов в обертку;
2. на каждой обертке слушаем событие `onchange`;
3. на каждое событие меняем количество отмеченных `checkbox`'ов, в зависимости от этого мы можем убрать/поставить "главный" `checkbox`
4. если же нажали на "главный" `checkbox`, то выделяем или снимаем выделение со всех `checkbox` в обертке.

Прилагаю свой пример, полная версия на [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5r6y8euk/4/):

```
var count = item.getElementsByClassName('js-checkbox').length;
var currentCount = 0;
item.addEventListener('change', function(evt) {
    if (evt.target.classList.contains('js-checkbox-main')) {
        if (evt.target.checked) {
            setAllCheckboxes(item, true);
            currentCount = count;
        } else {
            setAllCheckboxes(item, false);
            currentCount = 0;
        }
    } else {
        evt.target.checked ? ++currentCount : --currentCount;

        console.log(currentCount)
        if (currentCount == count) {
            setAllCheckboxes(item, true);
        } else if (currentCount == count - 1){
            if (!evt.target.checked) {
                item.getElementsByClassName('js-checkbox-main')[0].checked = false;
            }
        }
    }
}, false);
```

Операция `getElementsByClassName()`, особенно не от корня, очень быстрая, так что если количество `checkbox` будет динамически изменяться, их количество легко и незаметно для глаза можно пересчитывать на каждое сгенерированное событие.

Код полностью независим от каких-либо библиотек. Уверен jQuery делает это примерно также (могу обманывать в этом утверждении, но как сделать это по другому просто не приходит в голову). Интересно было бы протестировать скорость работы обоих вариантов, но почему-то мне кажется, что разница может быть заметна только на очень большом количестве элементов, которые в пользовательском интерфейсе будут глупо достаточно выглядеть. Поэтому данный ответ имеет смысл только в том случае, когда в вашем проекте практически нет jQuery и Вы хотите от него уйти или никто его не знает в команде jQuery (странновато звучит), или в чисто академических целях.)